# Is it possible to read the security permissions on a PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf

Need to detect if a PDF has permissions security when the document is uploaded.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: You could investigate the features of the various npm packages for PDF handling.

Comment: Are you asking about client side in the browser (in react)? Or do you mean server side in nodejs?

Comment: The reason I need to detect security is to alert the user that we may not be able to process the PDF before they go ahead on our system. Client-side or Node, will work, if they upload the file or if they drop in Dropzone.